# Can I legally connect a water heater pan drain to a shower drain?

Tags: water, shower, drain, heater

I'm remodeling a bathroom that has a walk-in shower. Adjacent to a shower wall is a closet containing the water heater. The water heater has a pan beneath it but it's not connected to a drain.

While I have the bathroom demo-ed, I'm thinking of running a drain line from the closet to the shower drain (connect just above the trap). See pictures.

Will this pass inspection? Is it acceptable code wise? Does the drain in the closet have to be "indirect" or can I plumb it directly with CPVC?

[image: shower drain]

[image: hot water heater]

[image: this is a indirect drain for those that have asked]

Comment: What is an "indirect" drain?

Comment: a floor drain with no direct piping.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the below sketch illustrates what you want to do.

[image]

This meets the code where I live. The drain pan connection to the shower does not need to be indirect, but the water heater's relief drain needs to be indirect to the pan.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. In my setup, which I didn't mention, the pressure relief valve is plumbed to a line (not part of sewer) that exits to the outside. I think this is also OK code wise.

Comment: If the trap in the shower clogged up, wouldn't it flood the drain pain under the hot water heater?